# Shell script in bash on Windows permission denied

Tags: windows, bash, shell

Following the instructions from http://www.techsutram.com/2009/05/bash-environment-on-windows-this-is-not.html, I have successfully installed a bash shell on my Windows machine. I then put a shell script (which I know to work) in the C:\bash folder, replaced the first line with #!\bash, and tried to run it from the bash prompt. It gives me a permission denied error. So I tried a chmod 755 on the script, but it still gives me permission denied.

Any suggestions as to how I might get this work?

Comment: Are you able to run a simple bash script, just echoing something? I ran many bash scripts on Windows with Cygwin - worked correctly.

Comment: I tried that, actually, `#!\bash echo "Hello world"` gives me the same error- permission denied. I tried chmod on that, too, but no luck. (Ugh, can I not do linebreaks in comments?)

Comment: Install Cygwin, if it's an option - it worked for me.

Comment: It's a little too bulky for my purposes; I'm trying to make this portable. Yes, I'm aware it can be pared down and such, but I prefer something that's sub hundreds of megabytes. I'd really just like to drill down what's causing this 'permission denied' error.

Comment: Ok, I just realized, from using `ls -l`, that the permissions aren't actually changed. They remain rw-rw-rw. And `su` gives me 'user root does not exist'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found a better version of a bash shell for Windows (more up to date, and an automated installation process), it's GNU on Windows, found here: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki

This works perfectly for me, and is considerably more lightweight than Cygwin.